# Load NON angular html page and javascript in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am working on a project with Angular 7, using the Core UI template. I have a page that in written in plain html and it uses some javascript and I want to load this page when the user clicks something. This page is not an angular module/component.

I have tried loading an other Angular module and then load the html I need page inside it but it did not work. And my gut says this is not the way to go.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
By clicking <span class="here" (click)="loadNonAngularPage()">here</span> you can load a non angular page.
```

And the function called is this:

```
  public loadNonAngularPage(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/non angular page')
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `<iframe>` if you want to still be in the angular app or you can use `window.location.href = '...';` if you want to change to the other webpage.

```
  public loadNonAngularPage(){
       window.location.href = '/non angular page';
  }
```

Comment: I got it working by using the `window.location.href='...'` solution, but I miss everything on the rest on the window (like breadcrumbs, side nav etc) I will try the <iframe> solution. Thank you!

Comment: Made it work with `<iframe>` too and the result is much better. I had to declare in `assets` in `angular.json` file the `src` folder. After that, in both cases I used the path below `src` to the `page.html` file to access it. Thank you!